Square root definition
Perhaps this is silly, but here it is:
If we search for the square root definition it goes as follows (taken from Wikipedia):
"In mathematics, a square root of a number $x$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2$; in other words, a number y whose square (the result of multiplying the number by itself, or $y\times y$) is $x$.
For example, 4 and −4 are square roots of $16$ because $4^2=(-4)^2 = 16$."
At the same time, if we look at the definition of the square root of a number squared, we get $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2} = \lvert x \rvert$.
These are totally fine and I know how to use them properly. But at the same time, we have one single function with seemingly two different definitions depending on which operand it operates on; in one of them we make use of the absolute value function, on the other we don't.
I'm not saying (obviously) that these are wrong or inconsistent, but would it make any sense (or perhaps be more elegant), if we simply defined the square root of a positive real number (squared or not) using the absolute value function, as something like:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x} = \lvert y \rvert, \iff y^2 = x$$
?
Thank you,
All the best!

It is standard when working over the real numbers to take the square root function to return the non-negative square root. This is called the principal square root and is described in the Wikipedia page you refer to.

@RobArthan And was detailed in my posted solution prior to your comment

"In mathematics, a square root of a number $x$ is a number $y$ such that $y^2$" and "At the same time, if we look at the definition of the square root of a number".  THere's a big difference between the words "a" and "the".

Having multiple equivalent definitions of a single concept is often useful. Depending on the situation in question one definition may be easier to use any one of the alternative definitions.

@Steen82, I had never thought about it like this. I had always thought that every concept would have just one single definition. But thinking about It now, you are absolutely right! Thank you

@BrunodePaulaAssunção Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

The square root, $\sqrt{z}$, of a complex number $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is defined as
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{z}&=e^{(\log(|z|)+i\arg(z))/2}\\\\
&=\sqrt{|z|}e^{i(\text{Arg}(z) +2n\pi)/2}\\\\
&=\sqrt{|z|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z)/2}e^{in \pi} 
\end{align}$$
where $arg(z)$ is multivalued Argument (a.k.a., the "phase angle") and can be expressed as the sum of the Principal Arguement, $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$ and integral multiples of $2\pi$.  Inasmuch as $e^{in\pi}$ can only assume the values of $1$ and $-1$, there are two distinct values of the multi-valued square root function.
As an example, suppose that $z=\frac{\sqrt 3+i}{2}$.  The magnitude of $z$ is equal to $1$, while the Principal Argument is equal to $\pi/6$.  Then we evaluate the sqaure root of $z$ and find
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 3+i}{2}}&=\pm \left(\cos(\pi/12)+i\sin(\pi/12)\right)\\\\
&=\pm \left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$
In real analysis, the domain of the square root is $\{z|z\in \mathbb{R_{\ge0}}\}$.  That is to say that $z$ is a non-negative real number.  In that case, we see that that the principal argument for $z$ is zero (i.e., $\text{Arg}(z)=0$).
We then choose to define "the" square root for positive real numbers as the positive value of $\sqrt{z}$.  This resolves the issue of multivaluedness.

(+1) Nice answer!

@Mittens That post does not look to be at risk for deletion.

Hi Mark, it got closed-deleted and saved from damnation yesterday. All kinds of interesting new and old postings are getting closed for the usual “context” stuff. Thanks for checking!

@Mittens Of course.  My pleasure.  This site is not the same site I enjoyed so much 9 1/2 years ago.  Back then, there were so many great questions and answers in real and complex analysis.

@BrunodePaulaAssunção Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

The function $ y = x^2 $ is not one-to-one, and so it's not invertible; or, its inverse relation $ x = y^2 $ isn't a function. This means that, for any given $x$, there may be more than one $y$ (in this case, at most $2$) satisfying this equation. We generally don't like to use multi-valued symbols when writing out expressions, aside from the very explicit $\pm$ symbol, because it hides some complication to the logic of manipulating equations and inequalities.
As such, we are motivated to find a way to split the multiple values (where they exist) into many single-valued ones. Since the relation at hand has 2 values everywhere which differ by a minus sign, except where $+0 = -0$, we could designate either branch with a symbol and get to the other by adding the minus sign. In $\Bbb R$, this manifests as a positive value and a negative value, so we choose the positive one as our designated branch.
Thus, we introduce the symbol $\sqrt{ \, \cdot \ } $ on $\Bbb R$ to be the (now) function which maps a non-negative real number to the non-negative real number whose square it is, i.e.
$$ x = y^2 \text{ and } x,y \geq 0 \iff y = \sqrt x $$
In $\Bbb C$, the situation is slightly less nice, because the two branches overlap each other: consider moving a point continuously around the unit circle once; the starting and ending positions of the square roots have flipped. As such, any continuous square root function must be multi-valued, or any single-valued square root function must have a discontinuity. We call that discontinuity a branch cut, and we can decide to put it anywhere we like depending on our needs. However, there is usually a canonical choice that we call the principal branch; in the case of the square root, the principal branch cut is the negative real axis, i.e. $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi]$.
When we re-interpret the square root on $\Bbb R$ as the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of the principal branch of the square root on $\Bbb C$, we end up with the non-negative branch we identified earlier, so these two definitions are consistent in that sense.

This is similar to my solution posted 30 or so minutes before.   Interesting that your solution received a (+1), while mine has not yet.
